# Wamp localhost not updating

Tags: html, css, wampserver

I'm developing a bootstrap website and I'm using wamp as my server. After working for a while, when I make a change and then refresh my browser, the change doesn't appear. I've tried to search through the StackOverflow and did everything, Like using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> and clearing cache, altering the inspect element things. Still, it didn't fix my problem. Hoping to get a solution now. PS: I was trying to add a navbar below the profile image.
Html:-

```
<DOCTYPE !html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Converter</title>
      <meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="TopSection">
        <img src="images/first_img.jpg" class="headimg"/>
        <img src="images/profile_img.png" class="profileimg" />
      </div>
      <!-- navbar -->
      <ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Css:-

```
 .TopSection {
  position: relative;
}
.TopSection .headimg {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
.TopSection .profileimg {

  margin-left: 550px;
  margin-top: 390px;
  height: 190px;
  width: 190px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 5px black solid;
  border-radius: 100%;

}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .TopSection .headimg {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
  }
  .TopSection .profileimg {

    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: 300px;
    height: 170px;
    width: 170px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 5px black solid;
    border-radius: 100%;

  }
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}
```

Comment: try private browsing.

Comment: try restarting wamp

Comment: Try both but still didn't worked

Comment: a few comments: don't use capitals in your classes / ids - OS's are case sensitive so it's best to play it safe and use lowercase 100% of the time - also it's best to download the external css / script files and save on server - if their server goes down, so does your site's js and stylings

Comment: The exclamation mark in DOCTYPE declaration should be before the DOCTYPE not html, this propably isn't what is causing the problem but and it might cause you other problems in future (and it really hurts my eyes :) ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prevent CSS file cache.Using the version method.like below

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?v=1" />
```

If you set caches to expire far in the future adding ?v=1 will let the server know this is a new file but you won't need to give it a unique name ( saving you a global search and replace)

Comment: The OP states that page contents survive a browser cache deletion so there must be something else going on, such as editing the wrong source code or the like.